# Formula for number of conjugacy classes in terms of characters

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $C_1,C_2,C_3$ are $3$ conjugacy classes in $G$. Fix some elements $y_1 \in C_1, y_2 \in C_2, y_3 \in C_3$ and define
$$N=\{(g_1,g_2,g_3) \in C_1 \times C_2 \times C_3 \mid g_1g_2g_3=1 \}.$$
I need to show that in terms of characters, the following formula holds:
$$\lvert N \rvert = \frac{\lvert C_1 \rvert \lvert C_2 \rvert \lvert C_3 \rvert}{ \lvert G \rvert} \sum_{\chi \text{ irreducible}} \frac{\chi(y_1) \chi(y_2) \chi(y_3)}{{ \chi(1)}}.$$
I think I need to use Schur's Lemma somehow, but I really don't know how to start.

Comment: What is the $\chi$ in $\chi(1)$?

Comment: $\chi(1)$ would be the dimension of the representation. I think it should be inside the sum rather. I have edited the formula.

Comment: This is a standard problem about products of class sums and the second orthogonal it’s relation

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.